# How can I only receive part of an HTTP web response in C#

Tags: c#, stream, httpwebrequest, readline, httpwebresponse

I'm wondering if there is a way in C# to get & read a HTTP web response but only up to a certain point. Example:

```
public static void Example()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://www.example.com/");

    using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using(Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using(StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                string line;
                while((line = responseReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if(line.Contains("stop!"))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will stop the stream from reading, but the response is still the whole page instead of just up to where "stop!" is found.

Comment: Why? /10chars etc...

Comment: You would have to write a custom browser to only send up to the "stop". Any standard browser is going to send the entire request. You however, can elect to stop reading the stream at any point as in your example.

Comment: So if the page contains many bytes of information, I don't have to waste time and bandwidth reading it after I have found what I needed.

Comment: Upload your webservice to Azure. It wont charge you for your web app crawling sites. Azure only charge for downloaded data.

Comment: You're not even storing the requested lines. How do you conclude you're still downloading the entire response? 'the response' in your question, as far as I can see, is a stream, not a 'page'.

Comment: Also note, unless you're sure what "ReadLine" sees as a "line", this might read the whole thing right away if the page doesn't use standard Windows line breaks. XML and HTML formats don't exactly care about 'lines'. I advise working with a buffer instead.